# Convert a mesh into Hair Particles?

Tags: particles, hair

I have a model in Blender, with the toon style hair. Is there a way I can turn the toon hair into more realistic hair particles?

Comment: no you have to manually add the hair particles into the head of miku, obviously delete the hair mesh.

Comment: Try HairNet add-on

Comment: Thanks Serge, I’m new so I have no idea how to mark this post as answered, but nonetheless you have answered my question